# Error with std::string::find() function

Tags: c++, list, class, stl, iterator

I get a runtime error stating that the list iterator is not incrementable.

```
void extractData::compareInventoryRecipe(string recipeLine)
{
    list<double>::iterator invenIterAmount = inventoryAmount.begin();
    list<double>::iterator recipeIterAmount = recipeAmount.begin();
    for (list<string>::iterator invenIter != inventoryItem.begin(); invenIter !=inventoryItem.end(); ++invenIter)
    {
        ++invenIterAmount;
        size_t found;
        found = recipeLine.find(*invenIter);
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the line with `found = recipeLine.find(*invenIter)`.
The members `inventoryAmount`, `recipeAmount`, and `inventoryItem` are within the protected scope of my class. This function is also a public function of my class.  Can someone please help me with this?

EDIT: The exact error says Debug Assertion failed. It lists the line and it says Expression list iterator not incrementable. I am sure which line the error occurs in because VS makes a breakpoint there.

EDIT2: the for loop was mistyped when I typed it in the forum. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Make your question title consistent with your observations! (Wich observations exactly BTW?? Compiler/runtime errors? Post error text verbatim in your question please!)

Comment: `++invenIterAmount;`  What are you doing here?  You sure it isn't this line that's causing the problem?  I am assuming you're using Visual Studio or similar compiler that has a debug version of the standard library.  If you are, you can't just willy-nilly increment an iterator just for fun.  If it goes out of bounds during the running of the loop, then you'll get the runtime error.

Comment: "Incrimentable"? Really? It probably means incrementable. Anyhow, you are incrementing an iterator past the past-the-end-position.

Comment: Copy and paste your code, don't type it into the post. Did you really use `!=` in the first `for` clause? If you can, use the new range-based for: `for( auto &invenIter : inventoryItem ) ...`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see what you are trying to say now. When I removed it, the program works now that I added it to the end of the loop.